# Get expanded recurrence using CSOM or at least filter future items on Lists.asmx

Tags: client-object-model, web-services, calendar

I need to get all events in a calendar, including series (with expanded recurrence), then I saw that I'm able to get this data using the `Lists.asmx` web service and `CAML query` from this link: https://gist.github.com/MartinBodocky/7984439. However, it returns all events, including past events, and uses the deprecated API.

I want to know if I can achieve the same result using SharePoint 2013 CSOM and if not, is it possible to add a filter to the `CAML query` bellow to get only events in the future?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> <soap:Body>
<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
<listName>831fdeff-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-c20d9ada3062</listName>
<query>
<Query>
<Where>
<DateRangesOverlap>
<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
<FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
<Value Type='DateTime'><Year/></Value>
</DateRangesOverlap>
</Where>
</Query>
</query>
<queryOptions>
<QueryOptions>
<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
</QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
</GetListItems>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can achieve it only via the `Lists` web service, if you have to access it from the client side. It means, no support in CSOM or OData / REST, see [this article](https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-get-calendar-recurrent-events-by-csom-from-sharepoint-2013/).

You can define a variable for the current date as:

```
var today = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var todayAsString = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Then you SHOULD be able to use its value in your query to restrict the result for the events in the future, if you use a double condition in the query part of your request:

```
string.Format("<Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Gt><Eq><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Year/></Value></DateRangesOverlap></And></Where><Query>", todayAsString);
```

But based on my experience, this kind of query won't work. If you include another `DateTime`-based condition in the query beyond `DateRangesOverlap`, the recurring events won't be expanded again. Just another 'kind' surprise from SharePoint. The expanding of recurring events seems to work only if you use `DateRangesOverlap`, and you use only this kind of `DateTime`-based condition in your query (but no other condition like `<Eq>` or `<Gt>` combined with a `DateTime` field).

You CAN however combine `DateRangesOverlap` with other kind of conditions (like `<Eq>` or `<Gt>`), as long as they are related to other field types, like `Number` or `Text`.

It means you should page through your calendar (by setting the `CalendarDate` `QueryOption`) to aggregate the calendar events, and if you are in the same year (month /week) as your start date, you should add an extra condition in your code (I mean C# or JavaScript, not in CAML!) to compare the dates. Really cumbersome.